# Обновление данных в адаптере

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

Нужно изменять цвет layout RecyclerView когда с сервера приходит обновление старой информации. То есть в начале при создании активити layout имеет один цвет, а когда данные обновляются он должен его изменять.

Добавлю для большей ясности: вот у вас есть чат, когда я пишу мое сообщение отмечено серым и оно не прочитано, я сижу в чате мой собеседник читает и мое сообщение становится прочитанным, и по этому условию я должен менять цвет. Организованно у меня так, что в адаптере устанавливается цвет RecyclerView, в который приходят данные из класса хранящего переменные.

Comment: Предполагается, что мы видимо, должны все написать за вас? Что вы сами сделали и что не получается?

Comment: Мне именно узнать как обновить сам адаптер, то есть изменить цвет лейатуа

Comment: Покажите код адаптера чтобы вам могли помочь, кто ж знает то, что как у вас там все устроено

Comment: @McDaggen код адаптера и не нужен. Background должен устанавливаться не в адаптере

Comment: @БорисовМакс А где он должен устанавливаться если он использует ресайкл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку вы считаете, что код лишний, чтобы решить вашу проблему и достаточно вашего описания, то опишу как ее решить:

1. Создаете два типа айтемов (новый.старый).
2. Поступающие данные должны иметь признак - новые или нет.
3. В адаптере переопределяете метод `getItemViewType()`, который будет по признаку из пункта 2 выводить нужный вид айтема.
4. При изменении данных (просмотрены) меняете признак пункта 2 и обновляете адаптер через `notifyDataSetChanged()`